# Jquery Mobile Listview not scrollable in android 2.2.2

Tags: android, css, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a Jquery Mobile Dialog box as written below:

```
   <div data-role="dialog" id="styles" data-theme="a">       
        <div data-role="header" class="header">       
            <h1>Styles</h1>         
        </div>
        <!-- /header --> 

        <div data-role="content" data-scroll="true" data-theme="a">   
            <div class="scroll">                         
                <ul data-role="listview" id="mylist">                            
                </ul>                                         
            </div>               
        </div>
        <!-- /content --> 

        <div data-role="footer" class="footermodal">               
            <h1>↕ Please Scroll ↕</h1>             
        </div>
        <!-- /footer -->    

    </div>
```

The ul content needs to be scrollable. In ios it is. Also in Android 4+ is is. But in Android 2.2.2 the content will not scroll. I have tried adding:

```
data-scroll="true"
```

Doesn't work. There is no style on it what so ever except for a height at this minute in time, and of course the jquery mobile 'theme' but i have removed that and it still doesn't scroll:

```
  .scroll{
    height:320px;
    overflow: scroll;

    }
```

I do no understand why it is not scrolling in Android 2.2.2. Does anyone know of this problem, have a solution or any help what so ever? Its driving me crazy. :/

Answer (score 1):

have a look at http://chris-barr.com/index.php/entry/scrolling_a_overflowauto_element_on_a_touch_screen_device/

Answer (score 0):

All android versions before 3.0 are bugged with overflow:scroll or auto ([bug info](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2911)).

From the article from Chris Barr and for thoses using jQuery here is a quick fix :

```
function touchScroll(selector){
      var scrollStartPos = 0;
      $(selector).live('touchstart', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        scrollStartPos = this.scrollTop + event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
      });
      $(selector).live('touchmove', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.scrollTop = scrollStartPos - event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
      });
}
```

and then if using modernizr :

```
if (Modernizr.touch) {
    touchScroll($('.myScrollableContent'))
}
```

but it's not ideal because all touch-able devices will have this.

Or, if you use Phonegap you can do (somewhere after phonegap inited):

```
if (window.device && device.platform=="Android" && parseInt(device.version) < 3){
    touchScroll($('.myScrollableContent'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with android < 3 and ios < 5.

Simple start is to add overthrowjs and the "overthrow" class to your scrollable content.

Then you can look into iscroll or other polyfilers.